# In groovy is it legal to reference private member variables from within a closure?

Tags: groovy

Sample code which can easily be run in the GroovyConsole under groovy 2.4.4:

```groovy
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

class Echo {
    public void text(String txt) {
        println txt
    }
}

class Test {
    private Echo echo = new Echo()
    @CompileStatic
    public void doStuff() {
        Closure c = {
            echo.text('hi')
        }
        c()        
    }
}

new Test().doStuff()
```

It fails with `java.lang.ClassCastException: Test$_doStuff_closure1 cannot be cast to Test`.

Interestingly, if I remove the `@CompileStatic` annotation or make the member variable non-private it works as expected.

**Edit:** filed JIRA issue [GROOVY-7558](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7558)

Answer (score 2):

I think you've uncovered a bug.  If it were expected that `@CompileStatic` would disallow access to the private variable, than this should fail too

```java
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

class Echo {
    public void text(String txt) {
        println txt
    }
}

@CompileStatic
class Test {
    private Echo echo = new Echo()

    public void doStuff() {
        Closure c = {
            echo.text('hi')
        }
        c()
    }
}

new Test().doStuff()
```

But it doesn't.  There are some Jiras that might be the same issue ([GROOVY-6278](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6278), [GROOVY-7165](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7165), [GROOVY-6468](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-6468)), but I'm not sure if the root cause is the same.  I'd say go ahead an open a new Jira for this.